# UITextField and UIImageView overlap tableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have the following problem, the UITextField and UIImageView overlap the tableView. If I select the location first and went back to select activities, the `UItextfield` for location will overlap the activities `tableView`

[image: Initial]

[image: Then]

## Code

```
#import "Search.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> 
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>
#import "Classes.h"
#import "MyTabBarController.h"

@interface Search(){

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSString *sURL, *strResult, *sRemaining;
    NSString *sLanguage;
}

@end

@implementation Search

@synthesize categoryMArray;
@synthesize autocompleteTableView;
@synthesize autocompleteMArray;
@synthesize sSelectedAdd;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];

     //=== Call the stored txtMemCode, something like session ---
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    sLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"txtLanguage"];

    //=== Pass the string to web and get the return Category result
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    sURL = appDelegate.gURL;
    sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"/apps/getcat.asp?"];

    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sURL]];

    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    //--- Configure the TableView
    self.txtActivity.delegate = self;

    UIImageView *imgforLeftActivity=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
    imgforLeftActivity=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
    [imgforLeftActivity setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"]];

    [imgforLeftActivity setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre or fit

    self.txtActivity.leftView=imgforLeftActivity;
    self.txtActivity.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    //==== Google Place autocomplete
    _txtPlaceSearch.placeSearchDelegate                 = self;
    _txtPlaceSearch.strApiKey                           = @"AIzaSyBJvZbCA-BiAE3HBgvrm6TTjAiVkYTU9Kk";
    _txtPlaceSearch.superViewOfList                     = self.view;  // View, on which Autocompletion list should be appeared.
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldHideOnSelection   = YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.maximumNumberOfAutoCompleteRows     = 5;

    UIImageView *imgforLeft=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)]; // Set frame as per space required around icon
    [imgforLeft setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"]];
    [imgforLeft setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];// Set content mode centre or fit

    _txtPlaceSearch.leftView=imgforLeft;
    _txtPlaceSearch.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    //--- Set the Navigation Bar to Transparent---
    UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [navigationBarAppearance setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  
    //--- Call the stored txtMemCode, something like session ---
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    sLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"txtLanguage"];

    if ([sLanguage isEqualToString:@"CN"]){
    
        [_txtActivity setPlaceholder:@"按活动搜索"];
        [_txtPlaceSearch setPlaceholder:@"搜索你所在城市的地方"];
        
    }else{
    
        [_txtActivity setPlaceholder:@"Search activities"];
        [_txtPlaceSearch setPlaceholder:@"Location"];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Optional Properties for Google Place AutoComplete
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteRegularFontName =  @"HelveticaNeue-Bold";
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteBoldFontName = @"HelveticaNeue";
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableCornerRadius=0.0;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteRowHeight=35;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableCellTextColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.131 alpha:1.000];
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteFontSize=14;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableBorderWidth=1.0;
    _txtPlaceSearch.showTextFieldDropShadowWhenAutoCompleteTableIsOpen=YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldHideOnSelection=YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldHideClosingKeyboard=YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldSelectOnExactMatchAutomatically = YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableFrame = CGRectMake(self.txtPlaceSearch.frame.origin.x,self.txtPlaceSearch.frame.origin.y+32, _txtPlaceSearch.frame.size.width, 200.0);

     [self cofigureAutoComTableView];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:    (NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if ([textField isEqual:_txtActivity]) {
        autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
    
        NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
        substring = [substring
                 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];

        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring{
    autocompleteMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [autocompleteMArray removeAllObjects];
    if ([substring length] > 0)
    {
        for(NSString *curString in categoryMArray)
        {
            NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
            if (substringRange.length > 0)
            {
                [autocompleteMArray addObject:curString];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"*******The autocompleteMArray : %@ ", autocompleteMArray);
    [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    //NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
    //[spinner stopAnimating];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    //NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"This returned response.write stuff %@", strResult);

    NSString *sSeparator= @"|";

    NSRange range = [strResult rangeOfString:sSeparator];
    NSInteger position = range.location + range.length;
    NSString *sLoop = [strResult substringToIndex:position-1];
    sRemaining = [strResult substringFromIndex:position];

    categoryMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i< [sLoop intValue]; i++) {
    
        range = [sRemaining rangeOfString:sSeparator];
        position = range.location + range.length;
    
        NSString *sCatName = [sRemaining substringToIndex:position-1];
        sRemaining = [sRemaining substringFromIndex:position];

        [categoryMArray addObject:sCatName];
    }

    NSLog(@"The Array : %@ ", categoryMArray);

}

-(void)cofigureAutoComTableView {

    autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.txtActivity.frame.origin.x,self.txtActivity.frame.origin.y+32,_txtActivity.frame.size.width, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];

    CALayer *layer = autocompleteTableView.layer;
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [layer setCornerRadius: 0.0];
    [layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

}

- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size: 14.0 ];
    cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 35.0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return autocompleteMArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.autocompleteTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =  [autocompleteMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSLog(@"Selected Cell %@", [autocompleteMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    _txtActivity.text = [autocompleteMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

#pragma mark - Place search Textfield Delegates

-(void)placeSearch:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField ResponseForSelectedPlace:(GMSPlace*)responseDict{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    sSelectedLat = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", responseDict.coordinate.latitude];
    sSelectedLong = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", responseDict.coordinate.longitude];

    //NSLog(@"SELECTED ADDRESS :%@",responseDict);
}

-(void)placeSearch:(MVPlaceSearchTextField*)textField ResultCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell withPlaceObject:(PlaceObject*)placeObject atIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {

if ([textField isEqual:_txtActivity]) {
        autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)dissmissKeyboardOnTap:(id)sender{
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    [[self view]endEditing:YES];
}


 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

    //=== Customize the UITextField
    [self SetTextFieldBorder:_txtPlaceSearch];
    [self SetTextFieldBorder:_txtActivity];

}

-(void)SetTextFieldBorder :(UITextField *)textField{

    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [textField.layer addSublayer:border];
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

}


@end
```

## With the most updated answer suggested by @Rajesh Dharani, the tableview went to the back of the textfield.

```
  -(void)cofigureAutoComTableView {

      autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.txtActivity.frame.origin.x,CGRectGetHeight(_txtPlaceSearch .frame)+40,_txtActivity.frame.size.width, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [autocompleteTableView bringSubviewToFront:_txtPlaceSearch];
    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];`
```

[image]

Comment: Change the Tableview frame in cofigureAutoComTableView  method like this way autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.txtActivity.frame.origin.x,CGRectGetHeight(self.txtActivity.frame)+40,_txtActivity.frame.size.width, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

Comment: Not working, it is still the same.

Comment: try this way autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.txtActivity.frame.origin.x,CGRectGetHeight(_txtPlaceSearch
.frame)+40,_txtActivity.frame.size.width, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

Comment: @RajeshDharani, tried your latest suggestion, the tableView went to the back of the textfield.

Comment: you can try like this [parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];

Comment: Not working still the same see updated answer

Comment: add this line [self.view bringSubviewToFront:autocompleteTableView]; in cofigureAutoComTableView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179874/discussion-between-hanz-cheah-and-rajesh-dharani).